# When verbally expressing metric units do people use decimal places?

Tags: speech, measuring-units

I am writing a script for an audio description, and am including an estimation of a statue that is 1.5 meters tall.  For metric users, would this be expressed in speech as:

"one point five meters" or
"one and a half meters"

If either works, then which is more intuitive?

Comment: Neither: *one and a half* is clearer.

Comment: What nationality audience are you addressing? Your spelling of "meter" suggests US, in which case nobody but scientists will understand you. Even in Britain you'd have a mixed reception depending on age. I'd think carefully about your audience and use either Imperial or both Imperial and metric. I won't answer your actual question, as that is expressly forbidden in comments and it is probably off-topic as a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Either one works, but 1 point 5 will likely sound a bit more precise and scientific than 1 and a half. If the statue was 1.6m tall, it would be more common to say one point six, rather than one and six tenths. Saying 1 and half might be a convenient rounding that could describe a statue that's actually 1.4 or 1.6m tall. If you use 1 point 5, you imply a precision indicating that the statue is not 1.4 or 1.6m tall, it is very nearly 1.5m.

Comment: A frequent way of saying it in Britain since we went metric (perhaps following the French idiom) would be "one metre fifty" (*Un metre cinquante*), or "two metres forty-five",  meaning 1.5 metres, or 2.45 metres..

Comment: @WS2 especially if it was 1.05m, saying "one point oh five" will confuse any non-technical listener while "1m 5cm" shoudl be clear

Comment: @mgb Trades people would probably say "one hundred and five", in that case - to avoid confusion between 1.05 and 1.50.